# admin system for uploading and displaying basic text and images in website. So things can be easily changed

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file-upload, placeholder

I am a novice when it comes to web design my knowledge is limited mostly to CSS and html.  So hopefully someone more knowledgeable can help.  I am try to make a sort of admin section where certain content can be changed like images and descriptions.  I assume this can be done in php.  I tried looking for what i needed but couldn't find anything I could edit to suit my needs

For example I have 4 featured images and descriptions.  These are smaller pictures with a shortened description.  When these are clicked it will take you to a page with a larger image and bigger description.  I want to make these smaller stuff and the larger stuff  editable via an admin system (basic page to upload the stuff) for someone with no coding experience.  This way they don't always have to ask me to change the stuff.  I then want to password protect the admin page but im pretty sure I can try the script at [this link for the password part.](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL#Things_you.27ll_need)

Edit: Im looking to have a basic web form that can be used to change specific info on the site (text and images but no styling).  I will then secure the page with the password system.  Essentially a really basic content management system.  If there is one that can be used with an existing site to do just what I need great I will use that.

Comment: This is really too broad of a question to be answered here. Try to break your problem down into specific questions about problems you are having in implementing your application.

Comment: It is called a CMS or Content management System and there are many free open source ones written by knowledgeable coders which would probably be more efficient than you trying to reinvent the wheel on your own with your level of coding experience.

Comment: Basically yes but a simplified version that would do just what I need.  I was thinking of just having a form he could fill out to change it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of a way you can do it(I assume you have a login system as there are admins), there would be a certain identifier for admins, let's say `user_level`..

Now either put the `user_level` in a session or you can check for it in the DB when the page loads..

Now you simply have add an if statement..

E.g: admins have `user_level` as 5.
so when they login I set a session variable as

```
$level = "" ; //get the user level from db
$_SESSION['user_level'] = $level;
```

Now put this in the script which shows the image

```
if ($_SESSION['user_level'] == 5) {
  //show option to edit stuff
} else {
  //show just the image
}
```

This just a basic idea..

Comment: nope I was just going to secure a webpage that had a web form that you could input the data into and have it display in the appropriate places.  At least that was the idea.

Comment: So how will you be defining admins?